# How to access openshift contained hsqldb server port publicly?

Tags: spring, openshift, haproxy

We are using HSQL Database Engine 2.3.2 with Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE while my spring configuration is as following:

Here is `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

    <bean class="com.chorke.spring.bootstarp.HyperSqlDbServer" id="hsqldb" init-method="start">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="server.port">55511</prop>
                <prop key="server.dbname.0">chorke</prop>
                <prop key="server.remote_open">true</prop>
                <prop key="server.database.0">file:~/.hsqldb/chorke/data;sql.syntax_mys=true;user=admin;password=pa55word</prop>
                <prop key="hsqldb.default_table_type">text</prop>
                <prop key="hsqldb.reconfig_logging">false</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:55511/chorke" />
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="pa55word" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is `com.chorke.spring.bootstarp.HyperSqlDbServer`

```
package com.chorke.spring.bootstarp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hsqldb.Server;
import org.hsqldb.persist.HsqlProperties;
import org.hsqldb.server.ServerAcl.AclFormatException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;

public class HyperSqlDbServer implements SmartLifecycle {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HyperSqlDbServer.class);
    private HsqlProperties properties;
    private Server server;
    private boolean running = false;

    public HyperSqlDbServer(Properties props) {
        properties = new HsqlProperties(props);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        if (server != null)
            server.checkRunning(running);
        return running;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (server == null) {
            logger.info("Starting HSQL server...");
            server = new Server();
            try {
                server.setProperties(properties);
                server.start();
                running = true;
            } catch (AclFormatException afe) {
                logger.error("Error starting HSQL server.", afe);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error starting HSQL server.", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        logger.info("Stopping HSQL server...");
        if (server != null) {
            server.stop();
            running = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable runnable) {
        stop();
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

As the following code snippet we are able to start **hsqldb** server on port **55511** in my local PC. But unable to start using **Openshift JBoss EWS 2.0** inside spring context. Where there is an error occurred as following:

```
[Server@15a1792]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@15a1792]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @15a1792,5,main]]: run()/openServerSocket():
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
        at org.hsqldb.server.HsqlSocketFactory.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.Server.openServerSocket(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.Server.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.Server.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.Server$ServerThread.run(Unknown Source)
[Server@15a1792]: Initiating shutdown sequence...
[Server@15a1792]: Shutdown sequence completed in 4 ms.
[Server@15a1792]: 2016-03-23 23:41:21.881 SHUTDOWN : System.exit() was not called
```

Regarding this issue my questionnaires are as following:

1. How to achieve permission to open an custom server port Like **hsqldb**, **h2db**, **MLLP**, **ActiveMQ**, **HornetQ**?
2. Do we need extra configuration to access custom server port if we are able to open an custom server port?
3. If there is an configuration required, would you please provide us any guide line regarding this issue?

Finally I beg your help to open an custom server port Like **hsqldb**, **h2db**, **MLLP**, **ActiveMQ**, **HornetQ** and access it publicly from **Openshift** Gear/Cartridge.

Comment: you said "inside spring container", can you post a `docker port spring_container`?

Comment: You may consider **inside spring container** as **inside spring context**

Comment: I found an option on [Openshift Cartridge Developer Docs](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#endpointss) but It would be slightly difficult to implement first time